# find match for two regular expression in Fluentd

Tags: regex, fluentd

i need to capture two different components from tail into two different tag. currently i am using the below code to capture one of the pattern. Please help on how two accommodate two regex

```
<source>
  @type  tail
    <parse>
      @type regexp
              expression /^(.*) Request(.*) CODE=(?<code>[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)(.*)$/
    </parse>
    tag req
  path /logs/MG_60100*.log.*
  pos_file /var/run/fluentd/access.log.pos
</source>
```

my other regex is

```
<parse>
      @type regexp
          expression /^(.*)Response: 200(.*)$/
</parse>
```

how and where to place this?? Please help

Answer (score 1):

defined two sources as below with different pos file. Worked for me

```
<source>
  @type  tail
    <parse>
      @type regexp
              expression /^(.*) Request(.*) CODE=(?<code>[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)(.*)$/
    </parse>
  tag req
  path /logs/*.log.*
  pos_file /var/run/fluentd/access.log.pos
</source>
<source>
   @type  tail
        <parse>
          @type regexp
              expression /^(.*)Response: 201.*)$/
        </parse>
 path /logs/*.log.*
 pos_file /var/run/fluentd/access1.log.pos
tag req1
</source>
```